# The Device Orientation method is not working for ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, orientation

My supports both Landscape & Portrait mode in ios6. I also try with new methods of device rotation, But the methods are not called & it does not support the orientation.

My code is as follow:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSLog(@"supportedInterfaceOrientations...");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    NSLog(@"shouldAutoRotate...");
    return YES;
}
```

I don't know the issue for this.

Thanks...

Comment: Check your target's supported interface orientations

Comment: yes, its supports all orientation.

Comment: check if supportedInterfaceOrientations and shouldAutorotate functions are present in all classes..

Comment: Are u using UINavigationController?

Comment: yes, but with split view controller

Comment: Then I guess both your master and detail have to support the orientations (these methods have to be implemented in both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Because You Mentioned : Deployment target is ios5 but you run the app in ios6.

In .pch File,

```
#define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] < 6.0 )

#define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] >= 6.0 )
```

And In Controller File, Check with Conditions,

```
#ifdef IOS_OLDER_THAN_6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
     return toInterfaceOrientation;
}
#endif

#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
     return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
#endif
```

Hopefully, It will be helpful to you.
Thanks.

Comment: but shouldAutorotate & supportedInterfaceOrientation is not called in ios6

Answer (score 0):

Do you support all Interface Orientations in the Target respectively in the `Info.plist`

[image: Supported Interface Orientations]
You would need to check all these images to support all `Orientations`

Comment: And the Interface does not Autorotate? Is your target iOS 6 or iOS 5?

Comment: Deployment target is ios5 but i run the app in ios6

Comment: And you also tried the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method (the old one)?

Comment: yes, but shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not called in ios6